# Changing Desktop Solid Color Via Registry

Tags: windows-registry

does anyone know where in the registry for a user the current solid desktop background color is set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HKCU\Control Panel\Colors\Background`

It's a string with a space between the numbers for red/green/blue, for instance for straight blue: `"0 0 255"`

Comment: I did it and the value is changing in the registry but the color of the background doesn't, if i tried from the control panel, it will work, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to reload the registry into memory, by restarting windows explorer.exe

Answer (score 8):

the command line "reg add" works well.  You can also import this registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; remove picture wallpaper
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WallPaper"=""

; set RGB = black
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]
"Background"="0 0 0"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the desktop background for a user in the registry.

First remove the wallpaper, if there is one:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallPaper /t REG_SZ /d " " /f
```

Then set you color. The values are in RGB so for example `"255 0 0"` would be red.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors" /v Background /t REG_SZ /d "0 66 117" /f
```

Answer (score 2):

The changes on the registry are not applied immediately.

A better alternative would be to use the windows function SetSysColors in C++.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19849675/3844137

Comment: Please note that the question was not about timings of changes. Alse please write the full answer you are giving and link references.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 1809, to set the wallpaper to Solid color: black (0 0 0)

```
:: BackgroundType: 0 -> Picture | 1 -> Solid color | 2 -> Slideshow
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers" /v BackgroundType /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallPaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors" /v Background /t REG_SZ /d "0 0 0" /f
```

Must logoff and login back to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors` settings and later wanted to revert back to the original settings, but couldn't find the default colour codes. In case anyone finds it useful, here is a screenshot I made from another system showing the default colour values:

[image: HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors showing default values]